# Can't update or install plugins in WordPress, php unidentified index

Tags: php

I just installed WordPress 5.2.1 on my new server. My server is running Windows Server 2019 x64 and IIS 10. I am running php 7.3.6. I have everything installed correctly and running.

I have also checked all of the folder permissions to insure that WordPress has write and read permissions, but when I log into my admin panel on my WordPress site and click on plugins and click any plugin to download and install, the download button returns update failed! The WordPress debugger is enabled and it shows an error at the top of the page:

`installation failed: PHP Notice: Undefined index: a:1:{s:3:"ssl";b:1;} in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wp-includes\class-requests.php on line 213`

Can anyone help me solve this error so I can get my plugins installed? I have been searching online for hours and still cannot find a solution.

Comment: Are you using WPML? Found this: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/white-screen-on-activating-wpml/

Comment: No I am not using WPML i found out what the problem was it was my php settings so i configured my php.ini and now everything i working thanks for your tho.